# laravel error HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel

Please someone help me , its my 1st time uploading my application on live server and i cant fix it tried evrything available on internet

i created a 2 folders in my root directory of hosting

1.laravel 
2.public_html

in laravel i put everything except the public folder
in public i put the public folder files

these changes i did in index.php in public_html

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

but im still getting this error HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to change string

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Also make sure that the storage folder is writable

Comment: tried require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php'; and require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php'; both still not working